# DHCP Reservation

Tags: dhcp

I have DHCP inplementation in my college hostel. Here we have 5-6 switches to which all hosts are connected and a router. So how is the DHCP reservation implemented if each host is not directly connected to router. Or can I implement DHCP reservation on a switch

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about residential networking, and questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're speaking about regular L2 ethernet switches this is not that hard. Forwarding works just because you're still working in a single broadcast domain. The server can differentiate between hosts by using chaddr instead of the MAC address on ethernet layer. Of course this requires the operator to know the MAC address of each student's laptop, which might be tedious.

Alternatively (still L2) the switches might intercept DHCP packets and insert [option-82](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3046), more specifically circuit-id. In this option it can reflect on which circuit (i.e. cable) the packet came in, this will usually translate directly to a room. The DHCP server then does reservations based on this identifier. So then administration is a bit easier and you can just assign addresses per room.

If it are L3 switches (basically routers), there are 2 options. Either they do DHCP themselves which returns us to the trivial case. Alternatively, the routers implement DHCP relay where they usually also fill out option-82 with something sensible. Again chaddr and/or option-82 can be used by the server for address reservation.

Note that while option 82 is officially called relay agent information, it's often enough inserted/modified by L2 aggregation that don't perform any relay function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do reservation on your DHCP server - which might be running on your router, but not necessarily. Theoretically you could have DHCP server running on switch (on Layer 3 switch), but I guess this is not the case for you. So look at your router for reservations.

Answer (score 0):

DHCP is "implemented" as normal, whether or not the DHCP server is in the device the computer is directly connected to - a discover is sent, an offer is received, a request is sent, an acknowledgement is received. So long as it's all one network (at layer 2) no particular setup is required to manage that - it's supposed to work, and generally does. Many of mine pass through 3 switches to and from the DHCP server.

If it's not all one network, you get into needing "helpers" to get DHCP requests from a network without DHCP servers to a server that lives elsewhere and hands out the addresses for that other network. This is more complicated.

Setting it up in the switches first requires switches that have the capability, and then it requires a fanatical dedication to documentation and management - if every switch is a DHCP server, you have a potential mess, and in most cases it becomes an actual mess. It's much, much less confusing to have a single DHCP server where you managed all the reservations and pools for non-reserved machines.

This **usually** IS the router/firewall in small networks, but it does not NEED to be - it can be a completely different machine, so long as it's on the network.

Answer (score 0):

A Switch typically does not perform DHCP assignment as it is not designed to do so

I am assuming and recommending this is your upstream to downstream connection

Internet | ISP Uplink > Router | DHCP Server > (5/6) Switches > Clients

All clients (I think that hosts is a misleading term here) downstream from the switches will request and pull IPs from your upstream Router | DHCP Server.

Depending on the capabilities of your Router | DHCP Server & Switches you may be able configure some amount of [Static DHCP](https://superuser.com/a/3845/183467) to assign and allocate 'specific' reserved IPs to certain clients/ machines/ switches without having to setup Static IPs on them and centrally managed those IP assignments from the DHCP Provider.

> Static DHCP: A DHCP reservation. This is actually a common feature but
>   little-known by most folks. It's quite useful for locking an IP
>   address to a machine, but wanting to keep centralized control over its
>   settings for DNS and default gateway, etc. Very useful.